# Codeigniter - array of json objects in post

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

In fire bug I view my jquery post request parameters, its like this

```
adults            1
applicants[]    [object Object]
attendees   1
children    0
```

In this post request the array called **applicants** contains json object which I want ti iterate over and pull out values in my codeigniter controller. The json string may look like this

```
({attendees:"2", 
  adults:"2", 
  children:"0", 
  grptype:"2", 
  'applicants[]':[{firstname:"John", lastname:"Doe", age:"33", allergies:"true", diabetic:"true",    lactose:"false", note:"nuts"}, {firstname:"Jane", lastname:"Doe", age:"34", allergies:"true", diabetic:"false", lactose:"false", note:"pollen"}]
})
```

Look at the applicants[] above, see I have info for two people as a json object. I am not sure how access the data in my controller. see this

```
$applicants = $this->input->post('applicants');
$this->output->append_output("<br/>Here: " . $applicants[0].firstname );
```

I was thinking $applicants[0] woild refer to the json object and I could just pull outs values on demand. Not sure hat I am doing wrong. Thanks guys.

**EDIT**
So I have adjusted my json and it looks like this

```
adults  2
applicants[]    {firstname:"John", lastname:"Doe", age:"23", allergies:"true", diabetic:"true", lactose:"false", note:"nuts"}
applicants[]    {firstname:"Jane", lastname:"Doe", age:"23", allergies:"false", diabetic:"false", lactose:"false", note:""}
attendees   2
children    0
```

Now I am still getting an error saying

```
**Message: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**
```

Any ideas ?

**EDIT 2**

Ok mu data now liiks like this

```
adults  1
applicants[]    {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe", "age": "34", "allergies": "true", "diabetic": "true", "lactose": "false", "note": "nuts"}
attendees   1
children    0
```

In the controller id did this

```
$applications = $this->input->post('applicants');
foreach ( $applications as $item)
{
  $item = json_decode($item, true);  
  $this->output->append_output(print_r($item));
}
```

This is the result of that logic

```
Array
(
    [firstname] => John
    [lastname] => Doe
    [age] => 34
    [allergies] => true
    [diabetic] => true
    [lactose] => false
    [note] => nuts
)
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, no matter what I do to access the dater I get an error to the effect that I cannot access it like that. How do I pull out the values ?

Comment: That you see `[object Object]` in the POST, means that is exactly what is going to be sent to the server - a string `[object Object]`. How are you creating the post data?

Comment: I have two forms in a widard and befor submit I create the json for each form and merge the json objects with jquery extend(). Then I send with jquert $.post(bla bla bla). Are t=you saing to send it accress as a string and not an object ?

Comment: Yes, you should convert the javascript object to a JSON string first and then send that string instead. Then, decode the JSON string on the server as @Sheikh Herra pointed out.

Comment: Can't believe I am so dumb, I used $item['firstname'] to pull out the value . Thanks guys for the guidance.

Answer (score 3):

You have to decode it on the server using

```
$applications = json_decode($this->input->post('applicants'), true);
```

So, it'll become an associative array and you can use it like an `array`, without the second argument (true) in [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the `json` will be converted to an object. Until you decode it, it's only a `string` (`json/java script object notation`  string).

**Update:** Since it's already an array of objects then you don't need to use `json_decode`, just loop the array in your `view` like

```
foreach($applicants as $item)
{
     echo $item->firstname . '<br />';
     echo $item->lastname . '<br />';
     // ...
}
```

According to the edit 2 it should be access as an array

```
echo $item['firstname'] . '<br />'
```

Comment: I keep getting an error that json_decode needs a string and I am giving it an array. I did a print_r and it just out put "object Object". I am sending an array of json objects, should that array be strings instead ?

Comment: @Binaryrespawn, then you don't need to use `json_decode`, it's already an array of objects, just loop it.

Comment: I adjusted my json string as outlined by EDIT 2 above. And used php array notation instead of object notation like $items['firstname'] to pull out the values. that works. Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

try this plz

```
$applicants = $this->input->post('applicants');
$json_output = json_decode($applicants );
foreach ( $json_output as $person)
{
  $this->output->append_output("<br/>Here: " . $person->firstname );
}
```

or

```
$json_output = json_decode($applicants,TRUE );
echo $json_output[0][firstname] ;
```